# Make wpa_supplicant ignore server certificate trust

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa, wpa-supplicant, ieee802.1x, 802.1x

How do I make wpa_supplicant accept any server certificate for PEAP MSCHAPv2 without having to manually put the public key in the client config?

Comment: It should be pointed out that doing this can be a major security risk: When using username/password authentication, the client will broadcast its username and password to any fake AP, making them easy to harvest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't include a `ca_cert` or `ca_path` tag/value pair in the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

From the example wpa_supplicant.conf file. Note the third sentence (emphasis mine):

`# ca_cert: File path to CA certificate file (PEM/DER). This file can have one
    #   or more trusted CA certificates. If ca_cert and ca_path are not
    #   included, server certificate will not be verified. This is insecure and
    #   a trusted CA certificate should always be configured when using
    #   EAP-TLS/TTLS/PEAP. Full path should be used since working directory may
    #   change when wpa_supplicant is run in the background.`